# jQuery .closest on $(event.target) disables other click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a jQuery plugin project, actually if it helps it's in github and you can see the full code at https://github.com/jondmiles/bootstrap-datepaginator/tree/1.2.0.

So I have an click event handler, one of the first things it does is use jQuery .closest to look up the DOM and find the parent anchor tag that the user has clicked.  This is necessary as icons sit in front of some anchors and I want consistency in the element I'm handling.

Here's the code in question, line 273 of /src/bootstrap-datepaginator.js in the project if you want it in context.

```
    _clickedHandler: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = $(event.target).closest('a');
        var classList = target.attr('class') ? target.attr('class').split(' ') : [];

        if (classList.indexOf('dp-no-select') !== -1) {
            // do nothing
        }
        else if (classList.indexOf('dp-nav-left') !== -1) {
            this._navBack();
        }
        else if (classList.indexOf('dp-nav-right') !== -1) {
            this._navForward();
        }
        else if (classList.indexOf('dp-item') !== -1) {
            this._select(target.attr('data-moment'));
        }
    },
```

Now I also have a datepicker (https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) which is attached to an icon element, added during the rendering process.

It looks like this, line 476 in the project

```
        if (this.$calendar) {
            this.$calendar
                .datepicker({
                    autoclose: true,
                    forceParse: true,
                    startView: 0,
                    minView: 0,
                    todayHighlight: true,
                    startDate: this.options.startDate.date.toDate(),
                    endDate: this.options.endDate.date.toDate()
                })
                .datepicker('update', this.options.selectedDate.date.toDate())
                .on('changeDate', $.proxy(this._calendarSelect, this));
        }
```

When the user clicks on the calendar icon the datepicker should appear.  It used to, up until a recent change but now nothing happens; no calendar.

I've tracked the issue down to the addition of the .closest() method which was a recent addition.  So it appears calling the .closest() on the event target some how suppresses the datepicker, but I can't figure out why, or how to work around this.

So to recap, when it worked line 275 looked like this

```
var target = $(event.target);
```

Now it doesn't work, line 275 looks like this

```
var target = $(event.target).closest('a');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you hitting exception? Errors in console? My guess  is that there is not always a 'closest a' on the target

Comment: In my experience the datepicker is a fussy SOB. Can you re-instantiate the datepicker at all after the `closest` call?

Comment: No exception, no error, and there should/is always a anchor. Plus the tenery expression handles such a scenario.  BUT the datepicker should still display when you click the icon, how is it related to event.target?